# How does this class work or how can you use it?

Tags: java, design-patterns, static

I fell over a class which looks like this:

```
public final class DatabaseType{

    public static final DatabaseType TYPE_LIMITED_TEXT = new DatabaseType();
    public static final DatabaseType TYPE_UNLIMITED_TEXT = new DatabaseType();
    public static final DatabaseType TYPE_DATE = new DatabaseType();
    public static final DatabaseType TYPE_DECIMAL = new DatabaseType();

    private DatabaseType(){
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "DatabaseType";
    }
}
```

I need to set the type but I want to understand what's happening here and I have no clue how this class works.
Whatever variable I use it will always return an empty DatabaseType, with no information. So I wonder how you can get use of such a class. Maybe there is a name for this type of class?

Comment: There aren't "static classes" in Java. What you are looking at, is a Singleton. This is a very limited implementation, I recommend asking it's author what it's all about, since it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, made a false title. It looks a bit like a singleton but there's no information in it. For me this class seems to be useless but actually it does what you think it has to do.

Comment: It does what I think it has to do? Sure hope not, since I think it's bit of a bogus class. The only "information" I see in that class is returned by the toString method, and is nothing but the name of the class. Far from usefull, if you ask me.

Comment: This looks like a very clumsy way to implement an `enum`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic unless this code was produced a long time ago before Java 5, in which case it is a very clever way to mimic an enum :) Except for the rather useless toString() implementation.

Comment: @Gimby, yes, the type-safe constants in the class are actually a much nicer way to implement an enum than the idiomatic `int` enums that you see in old Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the class lists four enumerable constants, which you can use like this in method signatures

```
public DatabaseType getTypeOfDB();
```

In client code, you'll have a type-safe way to compare the constants:

```
if (getTypeOfDB() == DatabaseType.TYPE_LIMITED_TEXT) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Even though the implementation seems a bit clumsy, it quite closely emulates a Java 5 `enum`, as Gimby pointed out in the comments. The good ideas in the design are the following:

- The constructor is `private`, meaning only the `public static final DatabaseType` instances declared within the class can exist
- The class is `final` so you cannot work around the above restriction by adding more constants in a subclass
- The constant fields in the class have *strong typing*, i.e. they are not `int`s, but instead `DatabaseType`s, which helps to eliminate bugs caused by typos or "magic numbers" in client code

The modern way to do the same would be using an enum instead:

```
public enum DatabaseType {
    TYPE_LIMITED_TEXT, TYPE_UNLIMITED_TEXT, TYPE_DATE, TYPE_DECIMAL;
}
```

Comment: I could find a class where it's used like an enum, so Isuppose that's the correct answer. Ty

Answer (score 1):

If you use call the function toString() you will always get the String : `DatabaseType`.
As i can understand you want to return the name of the variable you created that are DatabaseType.

---

Create a variable `private String name;` and modify the constructor like this:

```
private DatabaseType(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

---

Also create a function

```
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
```

---

Finally, when you create a databaseType object create it like this:

```
public static final DatabaseType TYPE_LIMITED_TEXT = new DatabaseType("TYPE_LIMITED_TEXT");
```